# Suggestions on a website that uses Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to build a website with the following requirements. I need help to see if it's possible at all. This website has a regular login (not Facebook). Upon being logged in, the user has the option to "attach" his facebook account. At this point I save the return user id in the DB. Then, I tried on another computer the following Facebook Graph API call with this user id but it said:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: You can only access the "home" connection for the current user. thrown in /home/public/vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1294
```

The call:

```
/{user-id}/home
```

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you're trying to call `/{user-id}/home` but are using an access token from a different user -

You can't fetch another user's news feed, only the current user of your app, using their access token

Comment: But that's the thing. I feel that if I created a $facebook = new Facebook(<app name & secret>) then (because the user registered with the app already) on behalf of the web application I'm allowed to get the user's feed anywhere and any time. It seems to make sense to me.

Comment: No, you should be using a user's access token to fetch data for that user - if you don't have an access token for a user you should only be able to access very limited information about them

Answer (score 0):

Try {user-id}/feed. If you are not using the accessToken that was generated by the facebook API on the "attach" time, you will be able to get only the public feeds/data. Using the access token that was generated at the "attach" time, you will be able to get data for your app permissions.

- About access token
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- How to use the graph api
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0